# Auto line break after 5 characters

Tags: php

Guys i just wanna ask if there's a possibility: for example `$currenttext = "someexamplepls";`
if you would like to show or print it just use `print "$currenttext";` then the prepared output look like this `someexamplepls`. My question is if i would like to print it like this:

```
somee
xampl
epls
```

in every 5 character there is automatic newline what should I do?

Comment: fyi, the quotes in `print "$currenttext";` are useless

Comment: y? explain pls i just a noob person. thx

Comment: Because you can display the value of a variable directly, without embedding it in a string that contains nothing else. In this case the variable is a already string anyway, so even if PHP had no automated type conversion it would work in any case.

Comment: @NullPointer: Not sure how that's helpful for this question..

Comment: sorry Stackoverflow for always asking a noob question :-(, thanks again ThiefMaster

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/wordwrap):

```
echo wordwrap($str, 5, "\n", true);
```

In case you want HTML linebreaks use `<br>` instead of `\n`.

Comment: ok Thief Master, your name is familiar? maybe on Github or u just answer some of my irrelevant question hahah thx